# In MuseScore, is it possible to add tab to an existing bass notation so I'd get both notation and tabs for bass?

Tags: notation, bass-guitar, tablature, musescore

I'm using MuseScore 2 and I've been wondering:

Is it possible to add tab to an existing bass notation so I'd get both notation and tabs for bass like you can have it for regular guitar? Basically I want something like in pic below but for bass.

[image]

I know that I can create guitar + tab in new project, where I get something like in pic above, change cleff to bass cleff and then change tab so it displays tab for 4 bass strings but what if I want two instruments in my project, for example guitar and bass guitar, to both have notation and tab? What do I do then?

Comment: Might be. I found the answer here - [Bass Instruments](http://www.basstep.com/bass-instruments-introduction/)

Answer (score 5):

The post is quite old, but I will answer it anyway.

Follow the post shown before by 'Awe', that is

"Under the category "Plucked Strings" you have all available string instruments to choose from, both standard notation and tablature for each. "

Now click on 'Add Linked Staff' rather than 'Add'.
The new stave will now be linked to the first

So if your first stave is Standard notation then you can make the second stave Tab notation.  Editing either the standard or Tab notation will affect the other

Comment: sometimes it helps just looking for an software update, we had right the other day a similar problem with another progra here in SE. (-> question "open MTP")

Answer (score 4):

You can add instruments to existing sheet.
Edit -> Instruments...  <kbd>I</kbd>

Under the category "Plucked Strings" you have all available string instruments to choose from, both standard notation and tablature for each. There you can add and remove as you like to your score.

[image: Add instruments to score]

**EDIT:**
As pointed out in [answer by Miki](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/52505/249), you can use the "Add Linked Staff" button to add a staff that is a dynamic copy with different instrumentation that will update automatically like you want.

Then you will get a score like this:
[image: Example]

Comment: But that way I'll end up with 4 voices, two written in regular notes and two as tabs, what I want to have is notes connected to tabs for both guitar and bass so that I would only edit sheets and have tabs already generated for me.

Because if I use your method I would need to rewrite, for instance, guitar part from notes to tabs in unisono and that would be a huge waste of time for longer musical pieces :/

Comment: You can make the bass part first in a separate project like you said you did, and then select and copy everything into this project at the right voice.

Comment: I guess there's no other way... It sucks. I guess I could make a template or two for the future but it's not a pleasant solution.

Comment: Copy/paste is quite fast and easy. You can even copy from one voice to another.

Comment: If you click on "add linked staff" and select tabulature for the resulting stave, you'll get a tab stave that auto-updates.

Comment: @neilfein: OK, great. I did not know this. I will let my answer stand as reference. Please upvote the [answer by Miki](http://music.stackexchange.com/a/52505/249) as he points out this.